# Horizontal Alignment of tabular and tikzpicture?

Tags: tables, overleaf, alignment

How to align a table figure and tikzpicture figure in a way that one is on the left and one on the right? How also to reduce their size so they could both fit horizontally?

```
\begin{tabular}{ | c | c | c | c | }
...
\end{tabular}

\begin{tikzpicture}
...
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to TeX.SE. Can you share a [minimum working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that)?

Comment: You could remove the empty line or add `\hfill` between the table and the picture and LaTeX would place both elements next to each other. For specifics, you need to share specifics: the exact table and the picture, etc.